# .htaccess - Redirecting in a real directory 500 error

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

*mydomain.com/forum/ is a real directory.*

When I do add these 2 lines to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/new-thread /forum/new-thread.php?comm=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) /forum/community.php?comm=$1 [L]
```

`mydomain.com/forum/` AKA `mydomain.com/forum/index.php` throws a 500 error, as well as all rules that are supposed to be changed by these lines. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add boundaries to your regular expressions. For example, the regex `^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` matches both `/forum/new-thread` and `/forum/community` so your rules are looping. You can either add the `$` end of string match to your regex or add conditions to stop the rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/new-thread$ /forum/new-thread.php?comm=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /forum/community.php?comm=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/new-thread /forum/new-thread.php?comm=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) /forum/community.php?comm=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/new-thread /forum/new-thread.php?comm=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) /forum/community.php?comm=$1 [L]
```